# Salesforce: Merge 3 Permission Sets into 1

Tags: salesforce

I have 3 'old' Permission Sets (PS1, PS2 and PS3) which need to be merged into a Permission Set #4 (PS4).

PS1, PS2 and PS3 will be deprecated after adding its respective permissions into PS4. PS4 will remain as the future Permission Set which will gather ALL the permissions for a specific set of Users.

For now, I see that this is a very manual task ("Eye-ball" comparing each PS1, PS2, PS3 with PS4 and adding the missing permissions into PS4) and, as all manual tasks, it is prone to errors.

QUESTIONS:

- Can you suggest a tool to COMPARE Permission Sets to make sure I am not missing any permission?
  or (even better)
- Can you suggest a tool to MERGE Permission Sets in a safe way (to mitigate risk of errors)?
  or
- Would you recommend a "best approach" or "best practice" for this task?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

**Developer way**

You'd need a developer to connect with sfdx (if commandline is scary - there's VSCode editor) or similar tool and download "metadata". And then compare the XML files using something like WinMerge

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quickstart-vscode-salesforce might help if you've never done it and don't have a developer handy.

Profiles and permission sets can be very big, what's being downloaded depends on what else you're downloading. Define "everything". If you indicate in "package.xml" that you want all objects, classes and permission sets - the permission set file should include checkboxes for "Apex Class Access", field level security, allowed record types etc - but might not include "Visualforce Page Access", tab visibilities etc because you didn't include them). There's cool [plugin to VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VignaeshRamA.sfdx-package-xml-generator) for building the "package.xml" file for you, picking what you need.

Once you have that you could load them up in Winmerge (or any "diff tool" you like) and compare up to 3 files. It takes a while to get used to (you could start with comparing two, not 3).
You'll see an overview of changed lines on the left and you can decide to say make leftmost file the merged one. Go line by line and add permissions as you see them. You could then save the final file as 4th perm set and use same sfdx/vscode to deploy it.

[image]

**Analyst way**

If you feel like Excel guru... This data should be queryable so you could export it and crack some comparisons that way. Again - the checkboxes would be spread across different tables so you'd need to compare object rights, then field level security, then class access, then...

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_erd_profile_permissions.htm

This would be a start

```
SELECT Parent.Name, SobjectType, PermissionsRead, PermissionsCreate, PermissionsEdit, PermissionsDelete
FROM ObjectPermissions
WHERE SobjectType IN ('Account', 'Contact', 'Case') AND Parent.Name IN ('PS1', 'PS2', 'PS3')
ORDER BY SobjectType, Parent.Name
```

[image]

It's very ungrateful job because you'd need to write formulas across rows or pivot it somehow... Also note my PS2 didn't have access to Cases at all - SF doesn't bother holding a row with all false, it just isn't there.

**¥€$ way**

Money solves everything, eh? Deployment & backup tools like OwnBackup, Gearset, Copado etc have something for detecting changes between projects on disk and orgs... You could rename PS2 to PS1 in another sandbox and make the tool compare them? (I'm not affiliated with any such tool vendor)

There's also https://perm-comparator.herokuapp.com/ if you're not afraid 3rd party app will get sysadmin access to your org (haven't used personally, just Googled it)

Ages ago my colleague got promising exports out of [Config Workbook](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q4evEAA). Again - haven't used personally, screenshots look nice.